# How to get the value of drop down list?

Tags: java, javascript, html

I want to get the value to of drop down list, to send back to server to match something.

**Update:**

Sorry, i has to be clear on my question. I am using javascript to get values in client side and sending those back to server with DWR & processing them with JAVA code.

`<select><option selected="selected" value="1">EEE</option><option value="2">ECE</option><option value="3">IT</option><option value="4">CSE</option><option value="5">MECH</option></select>`

'

```
<input id="id" type="text" size="5"/>
<input id="name" type="text" size="15"/>
<input id="age" type="text" size="5"/>
<input id="age" type="text" size="5"/>
```

'

I want to get the values(1,2,3,4,5) ALONG with the other Name, Id, Age values.
I can get field text using dwr.util.getValues().

How can I get that select option value?

Comment: Short answer, submit the form as post and the value will show up in your post variables. If this doesn't answer your question please supply more details.

Comment: Do you mean send it back without reloading the entire page, or AJAX? Please tag with a server side language, and/or [ajax], [javascript] or [jquery] if you are using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Since you specify no server-side language, I assume you want in HTML/JS.** So, use this code in javascript, assuming the ID of your combobox is `combo1`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var combo1 = document.getElementById("combo1");
   var val = combo1.options[combo1.selectedIndex].text;

   //this will show the value in a Dialog Box
   alert(val);
</script>
```

Comment: He does say "to send back to server to match something" so maybe he means AJAX. Either way, confusing question.

Comment: Yes, if he can code in `AJAX`, I just told him how to get the value. Rest depends on him, how to send this by `AJAX`.

Answer (score 1):

```
<select id="id"> ...

var opts = dwr.util.byId("id").options;
```

Comment: var employee = { id:null, name:null, age:null};
dwr.util.getValues(employee);
var opts = dwr.util.byId("id").options;
employee = employee.add(opts);


will it work?

Answer (score 0):

Try giving your select element a name attribute:

```
<select name='department'>...
```